# Unable to run Pipeline on Jenkins agent

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jnlp, agent

I am experiencing difficulties running a pipeline on a Jenkins agent. The Jenkins agent is connected to the Jenkins Controller through JNLP.

In the Jenkins Controller WebGUI, I can confirm that the agent is successfully launched and running. I have created a pipeline and specified the agent on which it should run, as shown below:

```
pipeline {
  agent {        
    label 'TestAgent'        
  }
    
  stages {
    stage('Retrieve Source Code') {
      steps {
        //steps
      }
    }
```

I have verified the agent configuration, pipeline configuration, and the connection between the agent and controller, and everything seems to be in order.

When I run the pipeline with the 'Built-In-Node' option turned on, the pipeline builds successfully. However, when I turn off 'Built-In-Node' and attempt to run the pipeline with the specified agent, it fails to build. The status shows "Build Scheduled," but no progress is made.

Furthermore, upon checking the Task Manager on the agent's PC, I see no Jenkins-related processes running. I have examined the Agent Log in Jenkins, but there are no relevant entries but in the system Logs, when I run the pipeline I see that the pipeline job is trying to run in Built-In-Node even after defining which node the pipeline should run on.

Also below have attached the images of the node configuration from the WebGUI

[image]
[image]
[image]

The Jenkins Version is 2.401.2 LTS.

Below given are the plugins used

[image]
[image]

This is the time difference between controller and agent PC's I notice. Could that have any impact
[image]

Are there any additional configurations I need to set up? Could someone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue?

It's worth noting that both the Jenkins controller and Jenkins agent are running on Windows PCs.

Comment: Can you provide a few more things, by editing your question: Version of Jenkins, Plugins being used and their versions, a screenshot of your Node configuration from the WebGUI

Comment: @djmonki have added the details requested. Not really sure why I'm unable to run the pipeline job on any newly created node as the pipelines are always trying to build in the built in node. Let me know if you need more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that stands out from your data is that your agent's name is `TestAgent`, and it has no labels. Yet your example pipeline definition targets `Gen2` label. In this specific example when the pipeline requests a node your agent doesn't match so the pipeline build keeps waiting.

Note that the Pipeline definition is always evaluated on the controller. You might see it on the `built-in` node on the unnumbered (lightweight) executor for short periods of time.

Comment: My apologies. 'Actually I created another new node and pipeline and configured them right, and when adding the screenshot forgot to change the pipeline script details. I can assure that the difference in the name is definitely not causing the issue

Comment: @joekevinrayan96, your pipeline syntax is correct, and if the label expression matches the name or labels of your agent, the task that the pipeline sends to the Queue should get assigned to the agent. If it stays in the Queue, either your agent is not online or something prevents the task from leaving the queue. However your mouse over the task in the queue and there should be a pop-up which explains why the task stays there.

Comment: This is what I find in the logs
'Executor #-1 for Built-In Node grabbed hudson.model.queue.WorkUnit@64b60af2[work=TestPipeline] from queue but Built-In Node went off-line before the task's worker thread started. No termination trace available.'

I could understand pipeline try to build in Built-In-Node even though we define it in the pipeline script.
@duemir does this give you any information also I have added the time difference between both controller and agent have a look at the question I have edited

Comment: @joekevinrayan96, what do you do exactly to the Bult-in node? As I said in the answer, evaluating the pipeline definition must happen on the lightweight executor of the built-in node. The best practice is to have 0 executors on it, but it should still be online.